# Coding Bat python Logic 2 question 3 Lucky_sum

Tags: python

https://codingbat.com/prob/p107863

> Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if one of the values is 13 then it does not count towards the sum and values to its right do not count. So for example, if b is 13, then both b and c do not count.

This is my code what's wrong with it? Need Help THX

```py
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    sum = a + b + c
    if a == 13:
        sum = sum - a - b
    if b == 13:
        sum = sum - b - c
    if c == 13:
        sum = sum - c
    return sum
```

Comment: Please fix your code so that it's formatted correctly. Python uses whitespace/indentations to determine what is in functions or `if` statements and such, so when you remove the spaces the code becomes ambiguous. You can use 3 backtick ` characters above and below the code in order to preserve the formatting.

Comment: "if one of the values is 13 then it does not count towards the sum *and values to its right do not count*" (emphasis mine). Your code instead implements "and the value to its right does not count." There's something wrong about your first conditional.

Comment: Instead of summing all values and then working out which ones to subtract, why don't you think of it this way: if a is 13 the result is X else if b is 13 the result is Y else if c is 13 the result is Z else the result is Q. Fill in the relevant values for X,Y,Z,Q.

Answer (score 2):

Might be overkill but you could use `itertools.takewhile` to continue summing values excluding a `13` if encountered and on. This would generalize to any number of arguments in an `*args` type of approach.

```
from itertools import takewhile

def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    return sum(takewhile(lambda i: i != 13, [a, b, c]))
```

Some examples

```
>>> lucky_sum(1, 2, 3)
6
>>> lucky_sum(1, 2, 13)
3
>>> lucky_sum(1, 13, 3)
1
```

Comment: I often forget about takewhile -- it's not a function that I need to use much and tend to just re-implement it (foolishly). Good solution!

Answer (score 1):

> if one of the values is 13 then it does not count towards the sum **and values to its right do not count**

Your code only handles the *immediate* value to `13`'s right, but the spec indicates that you should exclude *all* values to its right.

```py
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    sum = a + b + c
    if a == 13:
        sum = sum - a - b - c
    if b == 13:
        sum = sum - b - c
    if c == 13:
        sum = sum - c
    return sum
```

However if you could add an abitrary number of numbers, this becomes untenable. Consider instead something that scales:

```py
def lucky_sum(*addends):
    sum_ = 0
    for n in addends:
        if n == 13:
            break  # stop summing immediately
        sum_ += n
    return sum_
```

Comment: you may also notice that I'm no longer using the variable name `sum`. This is unimportant in this code, but since `sum` is a built-in function you should avoid shadowing its name. It is conventional to use a trailing underscore in this case, as in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

can try this:

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
  
  if a==13:
    return 0
  elif b==13:
    return a
  elif c==13:
    return a+b
  else:
    return a+b+c
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure what the final condition is meant to do. For example, if `a = b = c = 1` then your function won't return anything, but I think according to the problem statement it should return `3` in that case?

Comment: @Tim you are right. but i just went with the question and tried to do what was asked and didn't think of other cases. Also the site accepted it as valid solution in all the cases, so i didn't think further.

Comment: @MuhammadMohsinKhan i agree with your point and as "Tim" pointed out if fails when all 3 variables are equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
  xx = [a, b, c]
  return sum(xx[:xx.index(13)]) if 13 in xx else sum(xx)
```

Firt off my plan was to check if 13 is in the list otherwise I get an error.

If 13 is found in the list I use the index() method to get its position and then I use slicing to limit the values of the sum, it starts at the beginning, index 0, and stops at the index of the value 13 in the list.

Like that -> `list_example[:list_example.index(13)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    l = [a, b, c]
    i = 0
    total = 0
    while i < len(l) and l[i] != 13:
        total += l[i]
        i += 1
    return total
```

Basically iterates through the list from left to right & sums the values until a value = 13, in which case the while loop is broken.

Answer (score -2):

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    sum = a + b + c
    if a == 13:
        sum = sum - a - b
    if b == 13:
        sum = sum - b - c
    if c == 13:
        sum = sum - c
    return sum
```

To get a better sense of what's going on with the code, lets check for tests in which it's failing.

lucky_sum(1, 13, 13) expects 1 but returns -12

lucky_sum(13, 2, 3) expects  0 but returns  3

lucky_sum(13, 13, 2) expects 0 but returns -13

In your first *if* statement if A equals 13, you subtract A and B from the sum. Actually you want to not add either A or B or C together and return zero. Instead, you take the total of all three and subtract A and B and forget about c.  The second *if* statement acts separately from the first, meaning that if A equals 13 you perform one set of subtractions, then if B equals thirteen you perform a second set of subtractions, when really you only want to return A if B is found to be 13.  The third *if* statement also works separately from the first two, meaning that you already conduct two sets of subtractions and then if C equals thirteen you subtract C twice from the sum.  This is why you are getting negative numbers.

The situation in which you want to return A + B + C is only if no thirteens are found between A, B, and C so you want to save that condition in your else clause, and convert your *if* statements to *else if* statements so that they are all working together and not separately.

---

I believe the logic you're trying to represent would be more closely conveyed below.  The convention in most functions when calculating an output is to begin by setting the sum to 0 as this becomes the base case, and then to conduct some operations against that base case before outputting the sum.  If a equals thirteen, we ignore all of A, B, and C and return the base case where the sum we wish to return is actually zero.

In the case where B equals thirteen we want to ignore B and C and only return the sum of A, or in other words the sum of A and 0.

In the case where C equals thirteen, we want to ignore C only and return the sum of A and B.

And in the case where there is no 13 in A, B, or C we return the sum of all three.  This is why we save the sum of all inputs for the else case.

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    sum = 0

    if a == 13:
        sum = 0
    elif b == 13:
        sum = a
    elif c == 13:
        sum = a + b
    else: 
      sum = a + b + c

    return sum
```

---

Another way to think of this problem is that you are taking A, B, and C as a list of inputs on which you are performing an addition operation, which you stop if you run into a 13.

This can be represented if we convert the list of inputs into an array. Then iterate through that array adding the sum of each element to zero, and if the element equals thirteen we break the loop and stop adding to the sum.  At the end, like in the previous case, we return sum.

Remember, if all the inputs equal thirteen we do not want to perform any addition, but we still want to return a numeric answer of zero as seen from the expected output of the failed test cases. And the opposite is true when none of the inputs equal thirteen, then we want to perform the addition operation on all the inputs and then return the sum.

When considering problems like these always consider are there any conditions in which we do not want to perform any operation but still return an output. Start from the base case and build out the solution from there.

```
    def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
      
      nums = [a,b,c]
      sum = 0
      
      for num in nums:
        if num == 13:
          break
        sum += num
        
      return sum
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how your answer solves the issue?

Comment: @AztecCodes I have updated the answer to include an explanation.

Comment: Is this AI-generated?

Comment: Everything I've written is 100% human generated.